# PHP looping over JSON objects in my database

Tags: php, mysql, json

I'm storing some values using the mysql json field type, in Sequel Pro I'm seeing them as follows

```
["feature1","feature2","feature3","feature4"]
```

In my PHP file, I can print out the contents using

```
echo $plan->features;
```

but what I want to do is look over each one so I can style them, but the problem is when I stick it in a foreach loop I get the following:

```
Invalid argument supplied for foreach()
```

My loop is straightforward

```
foreach ($plan->features as $features) {
}
```

I'm not sure I'm doing things right.

Comment: First use json_decode then use in loop

Comment: What is the output of `print_r($plan->features);`? I don't see where you decode your json, nor where you assign it to the property `features`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a JSON String

```
["feature1","feature2","feature3","feature4"]
```

User `json_decode()` for the above string

```
$string = json_decode($teststring,TRUE);
```

And after that you can for loop the variable or foreach the variable

```
foreach($string as $single_value)
{
     echo $single_value.'<br>';
}
```

**Output:**

```
feature1

feature2

feature3

feature4
```

Comment: Store the json_string in a variable called `$teststring` and after that decode it as shown in my example and use it in foreach loop. Cool it will work..

Comment: @BigJobbies. Have you obtained the output or you face hindrance still. Let me know if my help is needed....

Comment: Welcome @BigJobbies. That is the reason i pointed out the Error at first for your knowledge. Glad to help you...